# How does my autoconf test program find files distributed with EXTRA_DIST (or some other mechanism?)

Tags: autoconf

I have a autoconf project. There are test files that I distribute in a test directory. That is:

Makefile.am:

```
...
EXTRA_DIST = test/file1.txt test/file2.txt
...
```

Now when I do a `make distcheck` these test files are put into the `.tar.gz` file. However, `make distcheck` builds the files in `./_build/` and then installs them in `./_inst` (I think?). One of my `check_PROGRAMS` needs to be able to find `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`.

That is, I have a check program called foo:

```
#include "config.h"
...

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    FILE *fd = fopen("file1.txt","r");
    ...
}
```

And my check program can't find where `file1.txt` has been copied as part of `EXTRA_DIST`.

What magic do I need to put in either `configure.ac` or `Makefile.am` so that the test program can get a `#define`'ed symbol and find the directory?

Answer (score 0):

If I really wanted to hard code the file location into binaries, I would do it similar to the following way, using either absolute (`$(abs_top_srcdir)`) or relative (`$(top_srcdir)`) path to the `test` subdirectory of the source tree:

```
EXTRA_DIST             += test/file1.txt
TESTS                  += test/mycheck1
check_PROGRAMS         += test/mycheck1
test_mycheck1_SOURCES   = test/mycheck1.c
test_mycheck1_CPPFLAGS  = -DTESTFILE_DIR='"$(abs_top_srcdir)/test/"'
```

```
/** \file test/mycheck1.c */
...
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fd = fopen(TESTFILE_DIR "file1.txt", "r");
    ...
}
```

However, I would consider not hard coding the test file location into an executable, and pass the file location to the executable via a command line argument or via an environment variable. That would simplify changing the file name or location by adapting the `Makefile.am` without rebuilding the executable.

The above assumes automake+autoconf. If you are using autoconf without automake, you can still use `$(top_srcdir)` and `$(abs_top_srcdir)`, but the build and dist and test recipes will need extra work.